# Creating a globally unique user ID

Tags: security, hash, public-key

I am building a system in which each user has an account with a linked public key pair. The matching private key is used to sign messages. Data describing the accounts is stored in a p2p-system, so we need a lookup key for each account, which is globally unique (i.e. a globalID (GID).
Question is: how do I choose these global IDs wisely? I mean in a manner that if there is an attack on the underlying p2p-system, an attacker would have a really hard time to exchange the keys.

I was thinking: Hashing the public key (with a salt), using this as the GID and signing the result would do the trick.
This way, if an attacker exchanges the key the GID wouldn't match any more (even though the attacker would be able to create a new valid signature). The only way for the attack to succeed is to find a collision for the GID, which can then be used as the public key, while there's still the problem of finding the matching private key in order to create signatures.

```
First approach: sha256(PubKey + Salt) = GID
Second approach: sha256(PubKey + Salt) + md5(PubKey + Salt) = GID
Third approach: PBKDF2(PubKey, sha256, Salt) = GID
```

Any thoughts on that?

---

EDIT: Some more details:

In this system/architecture, users should be able to setup an account with a globally unique ID, which is linked to an endpoint of some sort associated with this user. Very similar to the DNS. But without domains.
For signing purposes etc (not relevant here), each user has a public key pair. So the public key needs to be published in some way.

> Use case: Bob knows Alice's globalID and needs to "get" to her endpoint. She queries some system and receives a (signed) response comprising information about the endpoint as well as Alice's public key. With the public key, Bob verifies the signature. All done.

Now assume that there is no central authority and noone that runs a (semi-) central trustworthy system like the DNS that Bob can query. Solution could be a p2p/DHT system. So let's assume we use a Kademlia DHT to store and distribute this data records (globalID, public Key, endpoint data, signature). Problem is: everyone can easily overwrite any kind of data in those systems.

Scenario: Assume, an attacker Charlie could somehow overwrite such a record in an easy way by just creating his own new pub-key, setting the globalID to Alice's GID and signing this all with HIS private key. Now Bob would not be able to detect that Charlie is impersonating Alice by just knowing her globalID.

Therefore, the globalID should be directly linked to the public key, e.g. by using one of the approaches mentioned above. Therefore, when Charlie tries to attack again in the same way he would need to find a collision in the hash function and use it as his public key (then "generating" the matching private key to create the correct signature).

Question is now how to generate the GID from the public key or whether there is a major flaw in the system.

Hope this clarifies things a bit...

Comment: You could generate a 128 bits random number.

Comment: I started an answer for you, but I think you might be confused on one or two points. (Or maybe I'm confused.) First, please clarify the architecture of your system. Who can create an account? What do you mean by 'exchange the keys'? What attack are you trying to prevent: One user impersonating another? Why is standard asymmetric cryptography with each user being responsible to securing their private key insufficient? Normally, any message that can be decrypted with a public key is trusted to have been created by the private key. Any salt scheme is equally vulnerable to loss, leak or theft.